# how do i delete the previous version of dart sdk

Tags: dart

[this was when i tried updating the dart sdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9b1Zs.jpg)

i was expecting it to work but now its not even running on my vs code[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idvlv.jpg)
I was trying to run the program the output wasn’t showing then i saw upgrade dart sdk version some things might not work so they took me to the dart website i then open my command prompt and upgraded it but it seems it didn’t work

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), and that is about images, they are no even talking about photo's.....

Comment: research for less than 5 minutes, see: https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/dart-sdk